# Regression with constraints on the observations

Tags: r, regression, simulation

I'm trying to repeat the simulation from Berk et al. *Valid Post-Selection Inference'. He uses the following:

> Consider the models where $M_1: \mathbf{Y} = \beta_0 \mathbf{X}_0+\beta_1\mathbf{X}_1+\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ against $M_0: \mathbf{Y} = \beta_0 \mathbf{X}_0+\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$
>
> Suppose the covariates $\mathbf{X}_j$ are vectors such that $\|\mathbf{X}_0\|^2 = \| \mathbf{X}_1\|^2 = 1$ and $c=\langle \mathbf{X}_0,\mathbf{X}_1\rangle$.

I want to simulate the estimates of $\beta_0$ post-model selection. Berk does this and includes the following:

> Consider, for example, the scenario where $M_1$ is true with $\beta_0=0, \beta_1=1.5$, $c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\alpha = 0.05$ both for the two sided testing of $\beta_1=0$... Figure 1 shows a comparison of the nominal distribution $N(0,1)$ based on one million simulations of the response $\mathbf{Y}$.

I wonder how this simulation was achieved*, the paper does not tell in which dimension the vectors $\mathbf{X}_j$ reside*. I know the value of $c=\langle \mathbf{X}_0,\mathbf{X}_1\rangle= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ results in a angle of $45°$ between $\mathbf{X}_0$ and $\mathbf{X}_1$. I was thinking of simulating an vector $\mathbf{X_1}$ and then normalizing it, followed by a rotation to get $\mathbf{X}_0$ but how can I do this in `R`?

### Edit

Re-reading this question and I realize that $\mathbf{X}_0$ is just a vector containing all the observations. In his case this was a vector of 1 million observations. Edited the question on the angle-part.

I'm still unclear about the $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$-thing though.

Comment: My guess would be that it is to be a covariance/correlation between the regressors.